# Print out last count

Tags: c++

So, fairly new to C++ and coding in general, and I've been playing with counts and the Galton Board, how would I adjust the code so that it only prints the last row of count compared to the entirety.

```
   // Print all counts
   for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
      {
         cout << setw(4) << counts[i][j];
      }
      cout << endl;
   }
```

Comment: Go through your code line by line and examine what it does. You should see what you need to do if you find out where it produces a single row. Adjust that code.

Comment: Is `i` or `j` the row?  Or more directly what are the indexes of `counts[i][j]` that has the relevant count values?  The code has not nothing to do with a Galton Board which an unnecessary detail.  Also, your code is not self-contained so we have to do work just to figure how to help you.

Answer (score 2):

`SIZE-1` represents your **last row** and **last row** has `SIZE` columns print all the columns

```
  for (int j = 0; j <SIZE; j++){
     cout << setw(4) << counts[SIZE -1 ][j];
  }
  cout << endl;
```